# How to detect which word touched with CoreText

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, core-text

I am using CoreText to layout a custom view. The next step for me is to detect which word is tapped on a touch event/gesture event. I have done research on this and found advise on how to custom label a url to receive touches - but nothing generic. Does any one have any idea on how to do this?

UPDATE:

Here is the code within my drawRect: method
    self.attribString = [aString copy];

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds );

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)aString); //3
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [aString length]), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
frameRef = frame;

CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

Here is where I am trying to handle the touch event

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frameRef);
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(lines); i++)
    {
        CTLineRef line = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, i);
        CGRect lineBounds = CTLineGetImageBounds(line, context);
        NSLog(@"Line %ld (%f, %f, %f, %f)", i, lineBounds.origin.x, lineBounds.origin.y, lineBounds.size.width, lineBounds.size.height);
        NSLog(@"Point (%f, %f)", point.x, point.y);
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(lineBounds, point))
        {
```

It seems that CTLineGetImageBounds is returning a wrong origin (the size seems correct) here is one example of the NSLog "Line 0 (0.562500, -0.281250, 279.837891, 17.753906)".

Comment: I should add that all of the origins are very similar in value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "current context" in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. You are not drawing at this point. So you can't call `CTLineGetImageBounds()` meaningfully.

I believe the best solution here is to use `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()` to find the correct line (by checking the Y origins), and then using `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` to find the correct character within the line (after subtracting the line origin from `point`). This works best for simple stacked lines that run the entire view (such as yours).

Other solutions:

- Calculate all the line rectangles during `drawRect:` and cache them. Then you can just do rectangle checks in `touchesEnded:...`. That's a very good solution if drawing is less common than tapping. If drawing is significantly more common than tapping, then that's a bad approach.
- Do all your calculations using `CTLineGetTypographicBounds()`. That doesn't require a graphics context. You can use this to work out the rectangles.
- In `drawRect:` generate a CGLayer with the current context and store it in an ivar. Then use the context from the `CGLayer` to calculate `CTLineGetImageBounds()`. The context from the `CGLayer` will be "compatible" with the graphics context you're using to draw.

Side note: Why are you calling `UIGraphicsPushContext(context);` in `drawRect:`? You're setting the current context to the current context. That doesn't make sense. And I don't see a corresponding `UIGraphicsPopContext()`.

Comment: I haven't implemented the UIGraphicsPopContext() - I just put the UIGraphicsPushContext(context) in there temporarily to try and get CTLineGetImageBounds(), this way when I call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() I get the context that was last used. This was just a temporary work around.

Comment: I tried adding the code into drawRect: like you suggested but once again I get back line origins that are very similar to one another such as (228,16) and (222, 22) when these values do not seem to match with anything.

Comment: Try stroking the boxes you get back (CGContextStrokeRect). These sound somewhat reasonable (not certain what your view looks like).